# How can I display 2 items in a flex container and keep set width and height of a flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

*I have added padding inside the divs so you're able to see the boxes

I need to display these 2 items next to each other on desktop screen sizes.
I the purple bordered box which contains the 2 elements is set to display flex. 
The circle div sqaushes up.
I have set is to a height: 200px width: 200px - this is fine before I set the parent to display flex.
How can I make sure that the circle stays at the set width and height and the rest of the content  in the red box resizes - rather than the other way around? 
If you could also please explain like I'm 5 why this is happening that would be really appreciated.

```css
.card__inner {
  display: flex;
}

.news__feature-image {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
            <div class="news__feature-image"></div>
            <div class="card__content">
            <header class="news__header">
                <span class="new__post-date">
                    18 Sep
                </span>
                <a class="card__link" href="/">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </header>
            <h2 class="news__title">Lorem ipsum title this is a title etc Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed turpis est, eleifend.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

I have tried using flex grow and flex shrink on the feature image and the content.

Comment: Could you please add also your code? BTW, maybe the flex property (flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined) could help you in this issue: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: you should share your code. anyway flex-grow controls if a flex item grows or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added settings for the flex items that contains the circle. By default the setting for [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) is 1, which allows it to shrink if necessary. Setting it to zero ensures the circle is displayed as desired.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: thin solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.inner {
  border: thin solid purple;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```